# Laptop for Linux and I have a tight budget

Tags: laptop, linux, cheap

I have a very tight budget and I need a Linux Laptop for personal use on which to do basic computing tasks, as well as write code.

I need, at a minimum:

- 4GB RAM
- 64 GB HD
- 15 or 14 inch screen, 1080p would be nice.
- other basic stuff (headphone jack etc...)

New is preferable.

Linux is required - and that's what's making this hard. [On EBay, I see lots of laptops in the $200 range](https://www.ebay.com/b/4-GB-RAM-PC-Laptops-Netbooks/177/bn_7114668525?rt=nc&LH_AS=1&_udhi=350), but looking at each one requires looking up its Linux compatibility, and since they're used, you don't really know what you're getting.

What recommendations can you give me?

Answer (score 1):

[The PineBook 64 Pro is available for preordered delivery in October, is listed for $199 and has these features:](https://store.pine64.org/?product=14%E2%80%B3-pinebook-pro-linux-laptop-64gb-emmc-iso-keyboard-estimated-dispatch-in-october-2019)

> - CPU: 64-Bit Dual-Core ARM 1.8GHz Cortex A72 and Quad-Core ARM 1.4GHz    Cortex A53
> - GPU: Quad-Core MALI T-860
> - RAM: 4 GB LPDDR4 Dual Channel System DRAM Memory
> - Flash: 64 GB eMMC 5.0
> - Wireless: WiFi 802.11AC + Bluetooth 5.0
> - One USB 3.0 and one USB 2.0 Type-A Host Ports
> - USB 3.0 Type-C ports with alt-mode display out (DP 1.2) and 15W 5V 3A    charge.
> - MicroSD Card Slot: 1
> - Headphone Jack: 1
> - Microphone: Built-in
> - Keyboard: Full Size ISO type Keyboard
> - Touch-pad: Large Multi-Touch Touchpad
> - Power: Input: 100~240V, Output: 5V3A
> - Battery: Lithium Polymer Battery (10000mAH)
> - Display: 14.1″ IPS LCD (1920 x 1080)
> - Front Camera: 2.0 Megapixels
> - Power Supply included
> - Dimension: 329mm x 220mm x 12mm (WxDxH)
> - Weight: 1.26 kg (2.78 lbs)
> - Warranty: 30 days

It is on preorder for October 2019.

#### Caveats:

They are asserting that they are making this laptop available at this price as a service to the Linux community and that there are no margins for them in this product at this price point.

They also assert that if you would return it for having a few dead pixels, this is not the sort of laptop for you.

Disclaimer - I am in no way associated with Pine64. I just pay attention to developments in the laptop market, and this has really stuck out to me as of late as a really exciting development. I would also at least really like for them to cover their fixed costs on this, so I don't mind at all telling people about them.

Comment: You should check too if the processor architecture is supported in the distribution you intend to use, v.gr.: not all distros come compiled for the arm architecture, If you want to use a mainstream linux flavor perhaps the laptop you posted its ok, if not check your documentation to verify the support for arm. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Dell Latitude E-6410

https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=m570.l1313&_nkw=e-6410&_sacat=0

I use the E-6410 myself. A wonderful, durable, very convenient laptop for almost any Linux distribution. Keyboard backlight, matte display, titanium case - what else is needed? A corporate series laptop, so choose with a webcam (it is not installed on all laptops of this model). All devices are installed automatically, there are no problems with the drivers. I have been using such a laptop for many years (Ubuntu xfce) and do not regret it for a second. You can choose with a reinforced battery, you can choose with a reinforced battery with indication of discharge. In short, I am satisfied and advised and bought this particular model to many of my friends. The doctor and lawyer even transplanted to Linux on this laptop.

I use Microsoft Visual Studio Code, RubyMine. Installed ansible and puppet.

But in principle, anyone who has no problems with drivers for Linux will do. Whose Wifi, web-cam and bluetooth (if there is) works right "from the box"